# How can we stream the go pro video to Unity3D?

Tags: unity, c#, video, streaming

hi~ I want to render the go pro hero9's video on a texture in Unity3D. However, I can not visit go pro as a webcam according to the device index. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean it does not show up under [`WebCamTexture.devices`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-devices.html)? Could it be a missing or incorrect device driver? Are you able to use it as a video camera in other applications?

Comment: And have you verified that your problem is specific to this particular camera model? Did you confirm that your code is correct by testing it with a different camera?

Comment: @Philipp can use it in OBS.

Comment: @Philipp I tested other webcam it is ok!